# What is the name of this Dragon Ball character?

Tags: character-identification, dragon-ball

I bought this toy for my son.

Came along with a character named Cell.

Who would this character be?

[image: unknown toy]

Comment: Partly out of curiosity, did you buy that in a shop, with a brand and everything, or somewhere else, like a yard sale or something? I wanted to find the "source", so I'm Googling up `rayquaza plastic toy` along with various `dragon ball cell` variations, but while there are _a lot_ of toys for both, I didn't find that very one yet. So if you've got a lead to give me... :)

Comment: Hello LCarvalho, I see you've accepted the answer that it is Rayquaza. I'm still curious to learn, though: what made you think it was a _Dargon Ball_ character? Was it sold to you as one? Was it _packaged_ as one? _Enquiring minds want to know!_

Comment: Came along with the Dragon Ball's Cell character. I'm Brazilian and I bought at a newsstand ...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

That's not *Dragon Ball*, I think. It looks like the Pokémon [Rayquaza](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rayquaza_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), actually.

Notice the overall green, the little T-Rex-y arms, the golden pattern on the side, and the red edges on the rudder "separations" of his body.

[image: Rayquaza Pokémon]

Granted, the toy looks a bit shorter and its "horns" are shorter (and parallel), but it still matches a lot of Rayquaza's features.

Comment: One other notable difference is the jagged edges everywhere (ears, fins, back). But 100% agree that's a Rayquaza.

Answer (score 27):

If it's a *Dragon Ball* toy, it can only really be [Shenlong or Shenron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dragon_Ball_characters#Shenlong), the dragon that puts the "dragon" in *Dragon Ball*.
He is the magical dragon that is summoned by collecting all seven of the Dragon Balls. He has, like all good magical dragons should, the power to grant wishes.

[image: An image of Shenron]

Your toy is not a particularly *good* version of it, though. It does indeed share some characteristics with the Pokémon Rayquaza. It's possible that a lazy designer copied or re-used a design.

Comment: It's not uncommon for the same injection-moulded toy to be painted in multiple ways to represent completely different characters or objects from different franchises as a cost-cutting measure. Your Mileage May Vary on how convincing the results are for at least one of those options. So it's entirely possible that both answers are in fact correct and the toy was intended to be sold with different paint-jobs for each franchise.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300 definitely the Pokémon paint if you're right about this.